# Power sign in Input text box by html,css,jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to input square root and square symbol in input box by a calculator which has buttons, on clicking a button the value will be displayed on input box.
like x²+x³ or 2√13  +  3√4. 
i dont want to calculate the value just displaying these things in input box is the main problem.

Comment: you can do it easily, try using css before pseudo http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: we can use for square, sup(superscript) tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp

Comment: agree to @SiddaramH you definitely want to use ``sup`` tag. Then if you want to customize it somehow you cant just style it is css file using ``sup{}`` selector

Comment: The problem that he has won't be solved by pseudoselectors or  html tags. he needs to have symbol in input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input id="insert" value="√2+1²" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('insert').value += '²'">²</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('insert').value += '³'">³</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('insert').value += '√'">√</button>
```